# How-to overwrite directory on multiple places with 1 source directory

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

So today I encountered one of my PHP files was outdated so I've got to overwrite the `phpthumb` directory on the entire server.

Multiple websites use this folder on multiple unknown locations, so how can I overwrite all these directories from 1 source path? (ie: `/home/test/testuser/phpthumb/` to `/home/*/*/phpthumb/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo /home/*/*/phpthumb | xargs -t -n 1 cp -r /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/*
```

You have to work with `xargs`. Unfortunately `cp` cannot copy to multiple target. `cp` can handle multiple sources.

**Explanation:**

- `echo /home/*/*/phpthumb`: lists all `phpthumb` directories
- `xargs -t -n 1`: xargs should call `cp` for every line separately
- `cp -r /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/*` the command `xargs` should call. Note the target directory will be appended at the end by `xargs`.

Comment: This does the trick, however this will mess with the file permissions (since apache can't run dir/files with chmod 0/0 and owner/group on 0). Still working on a fix for this. Maybe you encountered this problem on a server with DirectAdmin installed?

Comment: Just want to clear some information up, your solution worked perfect. As mentioned earlier, my file permission got rekt by the root user. However, after writing a small .sh file I managed too chown username:username all the files with the name from the parent userfolder.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$ find /home -name "phpthumb" -type d -not -path "*test/testuser/phpthumb" \
    -exec cp /home/test/testuser/phpthumb/* {} \;
```

`find` command looks for `phpthumb` in `/home`:

- `-type d` select folder
- `-not -path` excludes `test/testuser/phpthumb`

For each folder perform `cp` command. If `test/testuser/phpthumb` is a tree with subfolder, add `-R` option to `cp`.